# TYPEORM RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "i" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm, parceljs

I'm trying to use type orm to set users in the database. when I was using typescript it worked just fine, but when I build it with parcel to js I keep getting this error:

```
RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "i" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
    at new RepositoryNotFoundError (D:\GitHub\discord-bot-test\node_modules\typeorm\error\RepositoryNotFoundError.js:11:28)
    at EntityManager.getRepository (D:\GitHub\discord-bot-test\node_modules\typeorm\entity-manager\EntityManager.js:649:19)
    at Connection.getRepository (D:\GitHub\discord-bot-test\node_modules\typeorm\connection\Connection.js:367:29)
    at Object.getRepository (D:\GitHub\discord-bot-test\node_modules\typeorm\index.js:269:55)
    at D:\GitHub\discord-bot-test\bot.js:20:5065
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

and I dont know why it doesn't work because the typescript does work...

I cant put the code here because its got to many characters...

can someone help me with this alone as context?

Comment: why you are using parcel to bundle backend code?

Comment: because this is for a discord bot that will run on heroku

Comment: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/355  it is only frontend bundler

Comment: Bro... I had the same problem, I was using TypeORM version '^0.2.41'. I migrated the project to version '0.3.6' and it solved.

I honestly don't know what happened, but in version '0.3.0' the 'RepositoryNotFoundError' error was removed and I believe something went wrong...

Answer (score -2):

Try putting `@Entity('i')` above your `export class I {}` inside the entity folder
I can't post an image, but like this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHuEF.png

Answer (score -2):

For those who are using nestjs you may get this error if you do not place proper imports in your corresponding module(s):

```
@Module({
  imports:     [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AaaEntity, BbbEntity, ...]
```